# Variable undefined

Tags: javascript

role="manager" and its says that "manager" is undefined.please help.

```
 function onSubmitClick(role)
        {
        .....

        <input type="b

utton" class="button" name="btn_Submit" id = "btn_Submit"  value="Submit"
                                                            onMouseOver="showToolTipMessage(T0097);showStatusBarMessage(T0097)"
                                                            onMouseOut="hideStatusBarMessage()"
                                                            onFocus="showStatusBarMessage(T0097)"
                                                            onBlur="hideStatusBarMessage()"
                                                            onClick="return onSubmitClick(<%=cstr(Role)%>)">
```

Comment: Imo your qn is not clear at all..

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes:

```
onClick="return onSubmitClick('<%=cstr(Role)%>')">
//                            ^---------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Does <%=cstr(Role)%> evaluate to manager when you click it? Try the following:

```
onClick="return onSubmitClick('<%=cstr(Role)%>')"
```